# Disable webview zoom in android

Tags: android

How to disable zoom effect in webview....i am trying below code but its not working for me

```
mWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
mWeb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1d1d1d"));
WebSettings mWebSetting=mWeb.getSettings();
mWebSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

setBuiltInZoomControls it won't disable multitouch zooming but this does.

Comment: Thanks @Chirag ......setSupportZoom(false) is working for me...Thanks a Lot....have a nice day

Comment: @user1679416 Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. Check this link . http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158971

Comment: ok...i have did check in arrow...i am fully new here so i was not aware of ....Thanks a lot...anything else from myside

Answer (score 0):

Sets whether the on screen zoom buttons are used. A combination of built in zoom controls enabled and on screen zoom controls disabled allows for pinch to zoom to work without the on screen controls

It will work from Api level 11 only..
see this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDisplayZoomControls%28boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

on Api 11 or greater you may be able to use

```
mWeb getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
mWeb.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```